# ReactJS Functional Component vs Component Functions for conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs, rendering

Sometimes I want to move my conditional rendering out of `render()`, and I always have dilemma between these two approaches:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  _renderSomething() => {
    const {x, y, z} = this.props
    // conditional rendering based on props
  }

  render() {
    return (
      { this._renderSomething }
      // vs
      { renderSomething(this.props) }
      // which one is better?
    )
  }
}

const renderSomething = (props) => {
    const {x, y, z} = props
    // conditional rendering based on props
}

export default MyComponent
```

Any performance difference between `_renderSomething` and `this.renderSomething`?

When should I use which?

Comment: A really good question! I'm curious here... There's another alternative though. You can create a whole new component and just call it like `<MyComplexComponent {...props}>`. And you can make it as functional component.

Comment: i think if we use _renderSomething() directly then we required instance of that function to access props.But in --const renderSomething...--we dont required this keyword

Comment: this is opinion-based and hard to advise you without seeing the *"complicated conditional"* part – it's those complications that help guide the trade-offs we're willing to make when we consider one approach over another

Comment: in general, a stateless component should just be a pure function that accepts props and returns the component to render – worrying about a function `f` or `this.f` is a micro-optimisation and shouldn't be considered as a primary guide for how your structure your code – allowing something like this to decide the structure of your code demonstrates a fundamental lack of understanding

Comment: @naomik thanks for your insight naomik. I understand where you're coming from. However my concern isn't really about the micro-optimisation such as `f` or `this.f`. And forget about the *complicated rendering* part, it's not my main focus here. Let's just assume the *conditional rendering* is a simple nested if-else.
My focus is that a functional component will be transpiled into something like `_createClass(renderSomething,[{}])` while the internal function will simply just be another `var _renderSomething = function...`. Any difference here? Seems like functional component is more costly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a performance penalty with Functional Components vs Functions returning elements. An example would be this -

```
// Component approach
let Tab = ({label, link}) => <li><a href={link}>{label}</a></li>;

class Tabs extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            // notice the key prop is handled by parent render
            <ul>{this.props.tabs.map(tab => <Tab {...tab} key={link}>)}</ul>
        )       
    }
}

// function based approach, notice the key prop is handled by the function
let tab = ({label, link}) => <li key={link}><a href={link}>{label}</a></li>;

class Tabs extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <ul>{this.props.tabs.map(item => tab(item))}</ul>
        )       
    }
}
```

In Component example, you will end up with unnecessary intermediate `Tab` components, which will add to the virtual dom, however small they are. And then as they grow, these components will eventually cause slow renders. React will need to keep track of these components over subsequent renders. And these being functional components, you would not have access to `shouldComponentUpdate` based optimizations.

The function version will not suffer from this as it returns `Elements` directly, instead of components. Also, with smaller functions, there will be gains due to code inlining.

An extended discussion into this approach is [here](https://medium.com/missive-app/45-faster-react-functional-components-now-3509a668e69f).

Answer (score 0):

in general, a *stateless* component should probably be a pure function that just returns the component to render

Below, you could replace `<EmptyList />` with `<ul></ul>` but the idea is you can abstract wherever you feel is necessary – in this case, I thought it would be nice to have some placeholder text for empty lists, so making it a stateless functional component was an easy choice

So little of your app actually *needs* state – in fact, you should be striving to remove it wherever possible. When nothing needs state, everything can be expressed with functions

```js
const EmptyList = ({ placeholder = "There are no items to display" }) =>
  <ul><li>{ placeholder }</li></ul>

const ListItem = ({ text = "" }) =>
  <li>{ text }</li>

const List = ({ items = [] }) =>
  items.length === 0
    ? <EmptyList />
    : <ul>{ items.map (text => <ListItem text={text} />) }</ul>
    
ReactDOM.render(<List items={[1,2,3]} />, document.querySelector('#list1'))
ReactDOM.render(<List items={[]} />, document.querySelector('#list2'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="list1"></div>
<div id="list2"></div>
```